# Filter by entries starting with in Low Search

Tags: low-search

I have a Low Search form which I'm using to perform simple text searches with on a collection. However I would like to also include the ability to search for all entries beginning with a specific character (A, B, C etc).

MY existing Low Search results tag is as follows:

```
{exp:low_search:results
        channel="book_authors"
        default:orderby="title"
        default:sort="asc"
        query="{segment_3}"
        result_page="explore/library/authors"
        limit="20"
        }
```

How would I now pass to this results page a search string which will return all authors with surnames (field name {a_surname}) beginning with 'A' for example?

**Update:**

Thanks to the pointers from Low I got this working with the following code:

```
{exp:low_search:results
        collection="book_authors"
        default:orderby="title"
        default:sort="asc"
        {if get:search:a_surname}search:a_surname="^{get:search:a_surname}"{/if}
        result_page="explore/library/authors"
        limit="20"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Field Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search) filter, and specifically, the `starts_with` parameter:

```
search:a_surname="A" starts_with="search:a_surname"
```

Which is identical to:

```
search:a_surname="^A"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a whirl... will that work alongside the query="" parameter or will I have to get creative with that?

Comment: As with all [Low Search parameters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params), you can hard-code them in the Results tag or add them to your Form as input fields. Or, for the first example, use one in your Form, the other on the Results tag. Capisce?

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat, removing the query= tag and wrapping the search:a_surname in a {if get:search:a_surname} conditional. :)

Comment: That's one way of doing it. If you're using GET vars, you can also just let the `search:a_surname=a` in the query string, and use `starts_with="search:a_surname"` on the Results tag. Slightly safer.

Comment: Yup but I also want the results tag to act upon a normal keyword search too... which I'm guessing this would prevent... :?

Comment: The Keywords filter and Field Search filter work sequentially, so they shouldn't interfere with each other. If the `search:a_surname` param is empty, it won't filter by surname. And the starts_with param only applies to search:-params that it contains; it leaves the keywords param alone.